# Is it possible to invoke a msg from a different class?

Tags: objective-c

I have been knocking my head against the wall trying to figure whether it is possible to call a function defined in a different class. Unfortunately, my limited knowledge in Objective C prevented me to reach a satisfactory answer. Basically, I have one class called `Caller` and a different class called `Functions` that I would like to hook to at run time. Class `Functions` will have all the functions defined that caller is going to reference to at run time. 
This is the code in its entirety:

```
--- Caller.h -------------------
#import "Functions.h"
@interface Caller
{
  int callerId;
  NSMethodSignature *sig;
  NSInvocation *func;
}
@property(retain) NSInvocation* func;
@end

--- Caller.m -------------------
#import "Caller.h"
@implementation Caller
@Synthesize func;
-(id)initWithFunction: (SEL)f
{
  if (self)
   {  Sig = [Caller instanceMethodSignatureForSelector: f];
      func= [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: Sig];}
   return self;
}
@end

--- Functions.h -------------------
@interface Functions
-(int)SayHello;
@end

--- Functions.m -------------------
#import "Functions.h"
@implementation
-(int)SayHello
{
   NSLog(@"Hello");
   return 0;
}

---------main.m-----------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Caller.h"
#import "Functions.h"
int main
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *  pool [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
   Functions* ftn = [[Functions alloc]init];
   Caller * c = [[Caller alloc]initWithFunction: @selection(SayHello)];
   [c.func setTarget:c];
   [c.func invoke];
   [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

The code was compiling fine but at run time, it encountered an error because `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector` is 0. If I make `Caller` class inherit from `Functions` class, then the program will work like a charm. But `Functions` class in my case has to be independent from `Caller` class. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:` returns `nil` because `Caller` doesn't have such a method - it is implemented in another class which you can't know with the given data at that point.

Instead you can retrieve the method signature from the target later, e.g.:

```
@implementation Caller
// ...
- (void)invokeWithTarget:(id)target {
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [target methodSignatureForSelector:sel_];
    // ...
}
```