# PerformSelector may cause a leak - Better solution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, warnings

I have a custom BackBarButton where I have a property to store a selector which can change in some cases. So I can't use delegation really smoothly.

[image: Warning description]

What can I do to get rid of this warning without changing the 'workflow' to delegation? The property is defined by using this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<SPUniversalBackBarButtonItemDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL delegationSelector;
```

I also tried to use this code, but it says 'No known instance method for selector...' and 'Implicit conversation of an Objective-C pointer to IMP'...

```
IMP imp = [[self delegate] methodForSelector:[self delegationSelector]];
void (*func)(id, SEL) = (void *)imp;
func([self delegate], [self delegationSelector]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expose your method in the protocol declaration. Then you will be able to call it without the need of a selector. And you won't have that warning.

OR

if you just want to get rid of the warning:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        //code here will ignore the warning
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: just FYI silencing a warning such as a a potential leak from an unknown selector is ill-advised, as the warning message is there for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

First why is your delegate strong? I really doubt you want a strong delegate. Most of the times you want a weak delegate because you don't want your object to dictate the memory status of your delegate.

An alternative to perform selector is [NSInvocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies):

```
NSMethodSignature * mySignature = [self.delegate methodSignatureForSelector:self.delegationSelector];
NSInvocation * myInvocation = [NSInvocation
invocationWithMethodSignature:mySignature];
myInvocation.target = self.delegate;
myInvocation.selector = self.delegationSelector;
[myInvocation invoke];
```

Comment: Thanks :) Changed the delegate to weak and the NSInvocation implementation is working really fine :)

Comment: It's crashing because [NSMutableArray
instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:self.delegationSelector]; returns nil. Why NSMutableArray?

Comment: Probably returns nil because of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301450/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-msg-from-a-different-class . So, you essentially need to do  `NSMethodSignature * mySignature = [self.delegate methodSignatureForSelector:self.delegationSelector];`