# Who can tell me that what those code mean?

Tags: ios

I am not a good developer
who can tell me that what those code mean? 
as simple as if...else...;

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
  // code here
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider a scenario you are writing a perform selector which is not implemented. But if you don't want that warning. Please declare like below:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self.ticketTarget performSelector: self.ticketAction withObject: self];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 1):

The code enables you to ignore compiler warnings between

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
```

and

```
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276178/5283648